# How to prove: if $a$ divides $b$ and $b\neq 0$ then $|a|\le |b|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a\mid b$ and $b\neq 0$ then $|a|\le |b|$

So far I have $b/a=c$, $b=ac$ but I am unsure what to do next/how to go about this. Step by step explanation please? Thank you so much!

Source: Elementary Number Theory Section $2.2$ by Burton

Answer (score 4):

If $a \mid b$, then for some integer $n$, we have 
$$
b=na
$$
Taking the absolute value we have
$$
|b|=|na|=|n||a|
$$
Suppose $|a|>|b|$, since $|n| \geq 1$, we have $|b|=|na|=|n||a|> |n||b|\geq|b|$ implying $|b|>|b|$, which is a contradiction. The rest is simple to see.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $$|b|=|ac|=|a||c|$$ and $|c|$ is a positive integer (why?). In particular, $|c|\ge1,$ so....